# Google webmaster tools add HTTP and HTTPS?

Tags: google-search-console

I have a website which is only reachable under https://www.... The http:// is 301 redirected to https:// and the https:// without www is 301 redirected to https://www....
In Google Webmaster Tools I have added the website twice, one with www and one without www. Is it necessary to add the http:// as well?

Thanks for advice.

Comment: What you have done sounds reasonable. Cheers!!